# $(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5}\right\rfloor)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to prove that $\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5}\right\rfloor\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Do you know what these two sequences look like?

Comment: have no idea about them any intuition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ and a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $\alpha \colon \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$, the composition $a\circ \alpha$, often denoted by $(a_{\alpha _n})_{n\in \Bbb N}$, is a [subsequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subsequence.html) of $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$.

For $\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to be a subsequence  of $\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5}\right\rfloor\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ you need to find $\alpha$ (as above) such that $\left(\left\lfloor\frac{\alpha _n}{5}\right\rfloor\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Can you find $\alpha$?

**Hint:** $\alpha$ is the floor function composed with something else.

**Answer:**

> Let $\alpha _n=\left\lfloor \dfrac{5n}3\right\rfloor$, for all $n\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: any help to find $\alpha$

Comment: @pourjour I added the answer.

Comment: thanks, it would be better if you have emphasized the steps.

Comment: Well, it's natural to try $\alpha _n=\dfrac{5n}3$, because then $\alpha _n/n=n/3$ and it serves our purposes. The problem is $\alpha_n$ needs to be a natural number, so I just took the floor of $5n/3$. You should still check that $\alpha$ is strictly increasing that the equality we want holds.